# Accepting Nominations — Who should moderate this site?

Tags: discussion, moderation

Ideally, Moderators♦ are elected by the community, but until the community is large enough to hold a proper election, we will be appointing three provisional Moderators to fill those roles.

We need your help. Please nominate folks you would like to see become provisional moderators for this site. Your input will provide valuable insight to help us make our selections. You can read more about the process here: **[Moderators Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).**

### The Nomination Process:

- **Nominate a user** by posting an 'answer' below. Each nomination should be a separate answer. Use the template at the bottom of this post to complete your nomination.
- **Self nominations are encouraged.** This is a volunteer activity, so users should not feel obligated to accept these positions. A self-nomination is simply a way to say, "I am very much interested in this, so let my record speak for itself."
- **Tell us about the candidates.** Nominations can include links to other activities like Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, or any relevant thoughts/links that may help us make an informed decision.
- **Nominees!** Please indicate your acceptance by editing the answer to accept/decline the nomination. And please ensure your profile email is correct so we can contact you. Optionally, you are encouraged to write a bit about yourself following your acceptance.

  > I accept/decline this nomination.
  >
  > Hi, I am name/location/fun fact (all optional). I live in <location>, so I am generally active on this site from <time> to <time>. Some other things you may want to know about me are…

### Here is what we'll be looking for in a Moderator candidate:

We are looking for members who are deeply engaged in the community's development; members who:

- Have been consistently active during the earliest weeks of this site's creation
- Show an interest in their meta's community-building activities
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in [**A Theory of Moderation**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

---

### Nomination Template

To nominate a candidate, copy and paste the text below as an answer and complete your nomination writeup:

> <a href="https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   <a href="https://bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/**UserID**">
>   <img src="https://bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/flair/**UserID**.png"></a>
>   ###Notes:
>   This nominee would be a good choice because …

[image]

Comment: Could we have an update on this? It's been two weeks now.

Comment: @terdon Nomination threads generally run about 2 weeks. The selection process should be starting now-ish.

Comment: OK, I was just wondering if you'd forgotten all about us! If 2 weeks (or, for that matter, more) is normal, that's fine. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 32):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

This nominee would be a good choice because (1) Devon is a highly experienced bioinformatician; (2) he is one of the top contributors [at BioStar](https://www.biostars.org/u/7403/) as well as at this SE; (3) he is a long-time moderator at BioStar; (4) he is friendly to both experienced bioinformaticians and fresh newcomers, which I think is critical to build up the community here.

**Edit**: I accept this nomination. Note that I'm in Germany, so I'm generally active from 0900-2300 there (GMT+1). -Devon

Comment: +1 Devon Ryan is one of the most active bioinformaticians on the Internet ever. I see him everywhere online. There is no reason why Devon shouldn't be a moderator here.

Comment: I would say precisely, that because he has a lot of commitments he might not be able to invest time as moderator here. But there's people who can manage very well their time! (all the best if you become moderator)

Answer (score 32):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

This nominee would be a good choice because (1) Konrad is a highly experienced bioinformatician and a top-tier programmer; (2) he is a [very active SO user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1968/konrad-rudolph) and familiar with general SE rules and features; (3) he has played an important role in publicly advocating this SE and pushing it to beta.

---

**EDIT:** I accept the nomination. I’m in the UK and generally online during work hours (except when travelling, which will unfortunately happen quite a bit before the end of the month). I have some experience with moderation as I used to be moderator on Skeptics.SE for a time. [I like people to be nice and to get along](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262791/1968) but I also think that ensuring quality in questions and answers is important.

Comment: Worth noting Konrad has 340K rep on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1968/konrad-rudolph

Comment: One small caveat to this nomination: will be travelling a lot without internet access this month.

Comment: From my interactions with Konrad on social media and other forums, I've been impressed with his breadth of experience and civil discourse. He would be a great asset to this community as a moderator!

Answer (score 26):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

I suggest this user as nominee because I think his view on [not closing questions too harshly](https://bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47/please-refrain-from-closing-proper-but-imperfect-questions-so-quickly) shows a welcoming and constructive attitude that could make this site avoid some of the criticism that stackoverflow has attracted.

Besides, this user has been reasonably active here and in stackoverflow and has shown his interest in this site's development in making the first two nominee suggestions.

**EDIT**: I accept this nomination. This is Heng Li here, living in US east. I greatly appreciate the friendliness towards new users at Biostars but also value the necessity of moderation.

Comment: Thank you for nominating me. I was hesitating whether I could be a good mod, but as you gave me a vote, I will try.

Comment: omg, it's my hero. I'd love him be the mod. Please vote him.

Answer (score 16):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

I have been very active on Bioinformatics SE, encouraging it through the nomination process via publicity on twitter and reddit, and participating in asking and answering questions, as well as participating in reviews throughout the private beta. I live in Wellington, New Zealand and work professionally as a bioinformatician at the [Malaghan Institute of Medical Research](http://www.malaghan.org.nz).

I am active on [SeqAnswers](http://seqanswers.com/forums/member.php?u=17049), [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/user/gringer), the [ONT community](https://community.nanoporetech.com/profile/david-eccles), and [twitter](https://twitter.com/gringene_bio), and spend a lot of time discussing my work with the research community. I report bugs in the FOSS bioinformatics programs that I use (mostly via [github](https://github.com/gringer)), which has led to a few research collaborations and published peer-reviewed papers (the most notable being [a paper](http://www.nature.com/nprot/journal/v8/n8/abs/nprot.2013.084.html) on the Trinity *de-novo* transcriptome assembler).

I am fairly new to StackExchange participation, but keen to learn. I've already found that participating in this community has filled in some gaps in my bioinformatics knowledge and public outreach.

Answer (score 15):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

I really want this site to succeed, and I would happily serve as a pro-tem mod. I am already a moderator on two other sites of the SE network so am quite familiar with the SE system and what it means to be a mod here. I am generally active and online between around 10 AM and 1 AM EEST (GMT+2).

Answer (score 8):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

I nominate myself even I have no experience with moderation on SE or BioStars, just because I would like to contribute. I would like to counterbalance my lack of experience in moderation with enthusiasm and creativity. I have hands-on experience with bioinformatics problems of evolutionary genomics (~3 years).

I live in Switzerland (GMT+1).

Answer (score 3):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

Although I nominee myself it would be my first time moderating a community, I am open to suggestions about how to improve my participation in the site (independently if I became a moderator or not).

I don't answer many questions on the main site, as I am at the first stages of my career (I am ending the master of bioinformatics next month), but I'll try to improve that. I have been following WGCNA tool thorough posts in [Bioconductor](https://support.bioconductor.org/u/7250/) support forum and [Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/u/9913/) to answer them (The links are to my profiles there). I usually work with R and Bioconductor.

I live in Spain, so I am generally active on this site from 0900-1700 (while working) and 2100-2300 (occasionally) here (GMT+1).

Answer (score 3):

[image]

[image]

#### Notes:

I have been trying to get exposure to this SE since the last proposal which got rejected because of lack of supporters. Since my second submission to reddit I got lot of help from [gringer](https://bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/73/gringer) and [Konrad](https://bioinformatics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/29/konrad-rudolph) in getting users to commit.

I am a bioinformatics Undergraduate so my contribution to bioinformatics SE is limited but I can help with the moderation by editing and fixing questions.

I am from Sri Lanka (GMT +5.30) so my active hours would be different and wouldn't overlap with other moderators.